# Parsing hash url to object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, url, cross-browser, url-routing

I would like to execute a process on the page load depending on what the hash in the URL is. I think I will need RegEx because I am looking for a pure JavaScript solution (no library dependencies).

What I am trying to do is if the hash is "#/products", then I will call "myIndex()"
else if the hash is "#/products/3", then I will call "myDetail(id)" where "id" is a variable to the product number.

Anybody have a good idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here’s a solution that checks for the literal string `'#/products'` first, avoiding the regular expression where it’s unnecessary.

```
var hash = location.hash,
    regexID = /^#\/products\/(\d+)$/,
    matches;

if (hash == '#/products') {
  myIndex();
} else if (matches = hash.match(regexID)) {
  myDetail(matches[1]);
}
```